# Where are arrays in structs Allocated?

Tags: c, struct, malloc

Let's say I have the following struct.

```
struct Vector3{
    double Values[3];
};
```

I know I can do something like:

```
struct Vector3 v1;
v1.Values[0] = -1;
printf("%f", vi.Values[0]);
```

And it will work just fine. I didn't have to malloc/calloc the .Values.
Compiling with -c99 -Wall gives me no warnings.
But I have a questions about such struct.

In this case, where v1 is a local variable:

- The 'doubles' of .Values are allocated on the stack or the heap?
- If they are allocated on the heap, is this code guaranteed to
  always work? Or is it compiler-dependent?

If have this other struct

```
struct Triplet{
    double First;
    double Second;
    double Third;
};
```

Could I "memcpy" the contents of a Vector3 to a Triplet?

Last but not least, what about this struct? Same rules as Vector3?

```
struct Matrix3{
    double Values[3][3];
};
```

Comment: Unless you do "malloc" everything is allocated on stack in this case. Check sizeof your struct.

Comment: Maybe the similarity of pointers and arrays confused you. Arrays are not pointers - your `Vector3` is very similar to your `Triplet`, and not at all similar to a pointer - so no need for `malloc` etc.

Comment: @anatolyg: That's basically what I was going to say. Suggested reading: section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com).

Comment: @anatolyg that would really explain the question, so I decided to elaborate a bit on it in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where are arrays in structs Allocated

The same place the struct itself is allocated, either on the stack or the heap depending on how you instantiate the struct.

> struct Vector3 v1;

Allocates all memory needed for Vector3 on the stack.

> Could I "memcpy" the contents of a Vector3 to a Triplet?

That depends on how the struct is packed on your target platform and based on your compiler settings and possibly #pragma affecting packing.  There is no general guarantee that you can just memcopy the data.  It will work on *some* platforms and can then fail on other platforms.

Comment: Author wrote ``struct Vector3 v1;`` That means stack is used, is not it?)

Comment: I see. So If I allocate it as a local variable, I don't have to "free" the array?

Comment: @Trauer note that even when you `malloc` the `struct` you only need to `free` the struct itself, not the arrays within it.

Comment: Perfect. Thank Eric and Kninnug. Great answers!

Comment: _So If I allocate it as a local variable, I don't have to "free" the array?_  _local_ has to do with scope, or life duration of a variable, not whether it is on the heap or on the stack.  It does not matter whether you create it as a _local_ or _global_, you do not have to free something if you did not use [m][c][re]alloc to create it.

Comment: @ryyker or you get it from a function that's documented to return an *allocated object*.

Comment: @FelixPalmen - The _scope_ of a variable has to do with its life span.  Access to locally scoped variables, those created for example inside `{...}`, will cease to exist once program execution flow leaves the curly braces, whether it was _automatically_ allocated on the stack, or dynamically created on the heap.  Explicitly freeing a variable, in any scope is only required if that variable was created on the heap with [m][c][re]alloc.  If a function documentation requires that its return be free'd, it is because somewhere prior, something was created using one of the `malloc` family of calls.

Comment: @ryyker yes, that's what the standard calls an *allocated object*. I didn't say otherwise. It has nothing to do with scopes, in scope, you only have the pointer to an allocated object.

Answer (score 4):

> 1) The 'doubles' of .Values are allocated on the stack or the heap?

They are **part** of your `struct`, that's what "member" means. So they're allocated wherever your `struct` is allocated.

> Could I "memcpy" the contents of a Vector3 to a Triplet?

In general: no. For example, arrays are contiguous, structs can contain unused padding between their members. It comes down to your *triplet* struct is not a compatible type to your *vector3* struct.

**edit**: anatolyg's comment to this question gives me an idea about how someone could come up with it, indeed, it's probably because arrays and pointers often "look" similar (and some very bad resources even claim they were the same).

They are not!

An array really is just a sequence of variables of the same type, this is even true for multi-dimensional arrays. The *stored object* is nothing else than the total number of elements declared (read: the *values*) in a row.

For a pointer, the *stored object* is an address.

What's often confusing is two things:

1. an array can't be passed to a function. When you do so, it's implicitly converted to a pointer (the function gets a pointer to the array).
2. Probably for ease of use, the *index operator* (`[]`) works on a pointer, too.

What happens internally with indexing (`[]`) is different. For an array, it just denotes the indexed element of that array.(*) For a pointer, it is assumed the pointer actually points to an array, so the pointer is incremented by the given index before dereferencing (thus accessing the indexed element of the array pointed to).

Example:

```
int a[5];
int *p;
```

now `a[3]` just accesses the 4th element of `a`. But `p[3]` is actually equivalent to `*(p+3)`.

<sub>(*) In fact, `*(a+3)` would be a valid expression, too, and according to the C standard, it *is* equivalent to `a[3]` because `[]` is defined in terms of pointer arithmetics. It works because an array is *always* implicitly converted to a pointer when used as one. Don't let this confuse you, it still isn't a pointer</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The struct is allocated as a whole, including the arrays.

```
struct Vector3 v1;
```

Here the full content of the struct (the array of three doubles) is allocated in the stack if this is a local declaration (inside a function), elsewhere it's in the static data area. Never on the heap.

> Could I "memcpy" the contents of a Vector3 to a Triplet?

That could probably work, but it would be a dangerous thing to do, because the layout of struct fields inside the struct is compiler dependent, `Triplet` could have padding between the doubles. In general, you should not `memcpy` different structs.

Regarding the last example (two dimensional array inside a struct), yes, it's the same as the previous, the nine values are allocated inside the struct.